# MongoDB finding within embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, querying, subdocument

Using the example found at:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Having:

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

and later querying:

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } } )
```

returns a set of documents having warehouse = A and qty=5 in "instock" subdocument

But querying just for those containing {warehouse: "A"} doesn't return any result

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A" } } )
```

Now, changing that to:

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock.warehouse": "A" })
```

works out

**Shouldn't be both the same ?**
Anything about the semantics ?

**On the other hand, what's the correct way to find for a field value that's in list of subdocuments inside another list of subdocuments (embedded of embedded)**

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the query:
`db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A" } } )` 
It checks for documents where `instock` array having only **one field** underneath it. In this case it just acts like `$eq` check. That's why you're getting zero results.

On the other hand, you have documents where both `warehouse: "A"` & `qty: 5` are present.

That's why your second query:
`db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } } )` return results.

The third query:
`db.inventory.find( { "instock.warehouse": "A" })` is the proper way to access fields inside embedded documents.

Instead of this query:
`db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A" } } )`

You can also use `$elemMatch` for accessing fields inside array of documents.
`db.inventory.find({ "instock": {$elemMatch:{warehouse: "A"} }})`

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your clear answer.
using $elemMatch means loosing performance ?

suppose I have a subsubdoc array embedded within a subdoc array in a doc, how to query for the id of a subsubdoc ?

Comment: `$elemMatch` match conditions within the same nested document, while dot notation match conditions on all nested documents. So if you want to check if a particular **nested document** has both `warehouse: "A"` &  `qty: 5` present, then you need to use `$elemMatch`. If you use dot notation instead, it will check in **all documents** that satisfies the condition. So check is not restricting to single nested document. Hope u understood.

Comment: @NelsonLaRocca 
thats going to be something like `"a.b":{$elemMatch:{c:"test", d:"test"}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul. I think MongoDB should go deeper in their docs about this topic. Thanks again.